# Read partial request body after "request entity too large" error

Tags: node.js, express

I have a node/express server and occasionally I catch a "request entity too large" error. This is good (I want the requests to be limited as they currently are).

However, when I do receive this error, I would like to be able to log at least part of the request body so that I can investigate what was sent in retrospect. How can I do that?

(Obviously, the request body can't be parsed since it is incomplete, so it would have to be the raw byes, which is fine.)

Thanks.

```
app.post(...)
app.get(...)
...
...

// Catch unhandled errors
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    // err contains the "request entity too large" error
});
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are working on? And what output do you expect?

Comment: I've edited my post with a snippet. I'm just putting an error handler after all other handlers which will catch the "request entity too large" (and other errors).